# Auto-Cast in Crystal - Can I tell the compiler to ignore type errors? (E.G. in a directive)

Tags: crystal-lang

Take the following code:

```
class Test(T)
  def initialize(var : T)
    @var = var
  end
  def +(val)
    if @var.is_a? String
      casted_arg = val.to_s
    else
      casted_arg = typeof(@var).new(val)
    end
    return @var + casted_arg
  end
end

puts Test.new(1) + "1" #=>2
puts Test.new("1") + 1 #=>"11"
```

If I try to compile this I get a compiler error: `no overload matches ...`

If I define `+(val)` as follows:

```
  def +(val)
    casted_arg = typeof(@var).new(val)
    return @var + casted_arg
  end
```

Then `puts Test.new(1) + "1"` works as expected (#=>2) and `puts Test.new("1") + 1` errors (clearly unhandled).

However if I define `+(val)` as follows:

```
  def +(val)
    casted_arg = val.to_s
    return @var + casted_arg
  end
```

Then `puts Test.new("1") + 1` works as expected (#=>"11") and `puts Test.new(1) + "1"` errors (clearly unhandled).

Ultiamtely, in theory I am pretty certain the code I have:

```
  def +(val)
    if @var.is_a? String
      casted_arg = val.to_s
    else
      casted_arg = typeof(@var).new(val)
    end
    return @var + casted_arg
  end
```

Should cover all cases? Why does it not compile? Due to type based compilation errors. Usually in these sort of instances I would use macros, however the problem there is that you cannot use `is_a?` or `typeof()` inside a macro... So then I thought maybe `{%begin%}-{%rescue%}-{%end%}` might exist, but unfortunately it doesn't.

I've been rattling my brains and I really can't see any way around it unless I can declare to the compiler "Hey can you just ignore compilation errors in the next declaration and just 'assume' it's going to work out?"

Is there really no clean way of implementing this behaviour?

Comment: It's impossible to help without actually having your compile error

Comment: @RX14 and I think, after some sleep, I understand why now... All types are evaluated only at compile time right? So the type of var would be `T` and thus the flow control will always go to the 'else' statement, thus this `typeof()` just cannot be used in this way? Or am I off the mark?

Comment: The `is_a? String` check does work, it's just that the compiler can't prove that it will *always* go one way or another. So the compiler thinks that for any time you call `+`, `casted_arg` could be set to a `val.to_s` (which is a `String`), or it could be set to `typeof(@var).new(val)` (which is an `Int32`). So when you reach the `return` statement, `casted_arg` is an `Int32 | String`, and you get the above error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues here with type inference in your code. First, as the compiler error says, after the if/else branches, the type of `casted_var` is the union of all types that can be assigned in both branches: `Int32 | String`.
Outside the `if` branch, the compiler doesn't know, that the types of `var` and `casted_arg` are always `String, String` or `Int32, Int32`.
I'm not sure, but *maybe* the type inference algorithm could figure that out. One day it might become that smart. But right now, it isn't.

For now, you have to move the operation into the if/else branch for the correct types matching up.

The other issue is simply storing `@var` in a local variable (see documentation on [if var.is_a?](https://crystal-lang.org/docs/syntax_and_semantics/if_varis_a.html) regarding instance variables.

```
class Test(T)
  def initialize(var : T)
    @var = var
  end
  def +(val)
    var = @var
    if var.is_a? String
      casted_arg = val.to_s
      return var + casted_arg
    else
       casted_arg = typeof(var).new(val)
       return var + casted_arg
    end
  end
end
puts Test.new(1) + "1" #=>2
puts Test.new("1") + 1 #=>"11"
```

Another option might be to implement this using macros to avoid duplication of the operation. This should be doable, but it also works without macros, so there is no strong need to do that.